# How to call an activity after click checkbox?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, fragment

I'm new in android studio and this is my first time using checkbox.I have a fragment `(Auto_Billing_Postpaid_Fragment)` and an `activity(AutoBillingActivity)`.I have checkbox with id name `"checkbox_auto_billing"` in fragment.Supposedly, after click in `checkbox`,it will open `AutoBillingActivity` .but after check the box,the activity did not open.I'd followed some similar tutorials but didn't work.What is wrong with my code or anything I missed?

**`Auto_Billing_Postpaid_Fragment :`**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    CheckBox checkbox_auto_billing = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_auto_billing);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AutoBillingActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**`AutoBillingActivity :`**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_billing);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
}
```

Comment: What does getActivity() do?

Comment: Show how you set onclick listener to the checkbox.

Comment: I think that is the thing that I missed sir @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this

```
CheckBox checkbox_auto_billing = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_auto_billing);
    checkbox_auto_billing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AutoBillingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

OR you can do like this also

```
checkbox_auto_billing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AutoBillingActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: is there any code that I need to change at AutoBillingActivity as well?

Comment: well I don't know about that. but i think my code will fixed your problem.Please vote if my answer will help you.Thanks

Comment: I used setOnCheckedChangeListener and its work thanks sir

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
CheckBox checkbox_auto_billing = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_auto_billing);
 checkbox_auto_billing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AutoBillingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //do something here
            }
        }
    });
```